# Is my proof logically sound?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Prove that for arbitrary sets A, B, and C that
$$ A \subseteq B \implies (A \cap C) \subseteq (A \cap B). $$

**My Proof**

Assume $A \subseteq B$. From this assumption we get  $x \in A \implies x \in B$. If we assume that $x \in (A \cap C)$ then $x \in A$ and $x \in C$. From our assumption, it follows that  $x \in B$. Since $x \in A$ and $x \in B$ we can conclude that $A \subseteq B \implies (A \cap C) \subseteq (A \cap B)$.

Comment: Completely correct.

Comment: You could add one clause "Since x∈A and x∈B, $x \in A\cap B$. We can conclude $A\cap C \subset A\cap B$."  But, yes, you proof and logic is sound.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This proof is correct! It can be simplified by noting that $A\cap B=A$ which directly implies the result since $A\cap C\subseteq A$. Written out completely, such an argument would go as follows.

> Let $A\subseteq B$. Then $A\cap B=A$. Since $A\cap C\subseteq A$ always holds,  we get $A\cap C\subseteq A=A\cap B$.

Answer (score 2):

Logically it is completely correct!

But maybe just add a little to that last sentence:

"Since $x \in A$ and $x \in B$ $\color{red}{\text{we know that $x \in A \cap B$, and thus}}$ we can conclude that $A \subseteq B \implies (A \cap C) \subseteq (A \cap B)$."